# Transfer iTunes to Ubuntu?

Tags: music, rhythmbox, itunes

How do I completely transfer my iTunes library (play counts , playlists and ID3 info) either to Rhythmbox or Amorak? Also I would like to sort my tracks by "date modified", is that possible?